# Location of hdfs files in pseudodistributed single node cluster?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have hadoop installed on a single node, in a pseudodistributed mode. The **dfs.replication** value is 1. Where are the files in the hdfs stored by default? The version of hadoop I am using is 2.5.1.

Comment: check the directory configured for `dfs.datanode.data.dir` property in the hdfs-site.xml

Comment: There is no such property in my hdfs-site.xml. What is the default value? I suspect the data of hdfs is being saved in /tmp/hadoop-username/dfs directory though.

Comment: Default value for `dfs.datanode.data.dir` is `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data`, where `hadoop.tmp.dir` is `/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dfs.datanode.data.dir: Determines where on the local filesystem an DFS data node should store its blocks. If this is a comma-delimited list of directories, then data will be stored in all named directories, typically on different devices. Directories that do not exist are ignored.

Default value of this property is: file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data
You can configure ${hadoop.tmp.dir} in core-site.xml file. Its default value is: /tmp/hadoop-${user.name}

References:

1. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml
2. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml